# Return id and rev after a PouchDB operation

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework, pouchdb

**Question**: How can I get `id` and `rev` after a `PouchDB` operation?

I do a document creation like that:

```
  createEvent(event){
    let res;
    res = this.db.post(event);
    return res;
  }
```

In the console I can see the result like:

[image]

And now I try simply to get that value out:

```
console.log(result);
console.log("id: " + result.__zone_symbol__value.id);
console.log("rev: " + result.__zone_symbol__value.rev);
```

How can I parse that correctly so I will be able to return `id` and `rev` in `PouchDB`?

Answer (score 0):

What db.post returns is not the information about the new document. As it is an asynchronous operation it returns a Javascript Promise (or alternatively a callback) that you can use to get the information once it has completed.

There is better information in [the PouchDb API reference](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#create_document).

They give an example of db.post which I will copy here for reference:

```
db.post({
  title: 'Ziggy Stardust'
}).then(function (response) {
  // handle response
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

and the expected value of "response" if you logged this in the console is:

```
{
  "ok" : true,
  "id" : "8A2C3761-FFD5-4770-9B8C-38C33CED300A",
  "rev" : "1-d3a8e0e5aa7c8fff0c376dac2d8a4007"
}
```

...and to answer your question directly, you could use

```
console.log(response.id);
```

below the "//handle response" comment to parse the information returned and show the document id.

Hope this helps you.